# Difference between AsParallel andAsParallel.Select in C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am wondering what is the diiference between Difference between AsParallel andAsParallel.Select() in C#, as both returns instance of AsParallelQuery.
Consider following code snippet:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

            var parallelList = list.AsParallel();
            foreach (var num in parallelList)
                System.Console.WriteLine(num);//returns 1 ..100 in order

            var query = list.AsParallel().Select(num => num); 

            foreach (var num in query)
                System.Console.WriteLine(num);/*returns 1..100 not in order*/

            parallelList.ForEach(System.Console.WriteLine); //returns 1 ..100 in order
```

I wonder, how list.AsParallel() and list.AsParallel().Select() interpreted differently

Comment: ``Select`` transforms the elements of the list into a another form. In your code sample, select simply outputs the same element as it receives as input, hence not really doing anything differently than the ``list.AsParallel()`` without the ``Select``.

Comment: but how iteration over `ParallelQuery<T>` making them ordered, as per my understanding, `AsParallel()`, should fire the query in parallel(data parallelism) and result should be collected not in order as well

Comment: You do the iteration in `foreach` statement, which is not aware about the parallelization, it simply iterates over collection in **one** thread

Answer (score 3):

What `AsParallel()` does is that it means any following LINQ methods will be executed in parallel. What it does *not* directly affect is how `foreach` behaves.

So, this:

```
var parallelList = list.AsParallel();

foreach (var num in parallelList)
    System.Console.WriteLine(num);//returns 1 ..100 in order
```

is just a confusing way to iterate `list`. It does not parallelize anything.

While this:

```
var query = list.AsParallel().Select(num => num); 

foreach (var num in query)
    System.Console.WriteLine(num);/*returns 1..100 not in order*/
```

executes the (useless) `Select` query in parallel, which may change the order of elements. But the `foreach` still executes on a single thread.

Finally, this:

```
parallelList.ForEach(System.Console.WriteLine); //returns 1 ..100 in order
```

does not compile, unless you have some custom `ForEach` extension method, likely behaving the same as `foreach`. (There is `ForAll`, but that's different.)